# How to save text into a UTF-8 file with/without BOM in PHP?

Tags: php, file

Does PHP have such options when saving file?

Answer (score 4):

PHP will never automatically append a BOM when writing a file. You would have to add it yourself:

```
$filecontents = chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF).$mycontents;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Thanks!
`$file = fopen("arquivos_gerados/teste.html","w");
    fwrite($file,chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF).$content);
    fclose($file);`